# buildr build aborted - unable to download from repo

Tags: java, jruby, buildr

Buildr build is aborting because failed to download from maven repo.

Given the very basic buildr file (mostly generated):

```
repositories.remote << "http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2/"

define "demo" do
  project.version = "1"
  project.group = "dirwatch"
  compile.with # Add classpath dependencies
  test.compile.with # Add classpath dependencies
  package(:jar)
end
```

Full stack trace:

```
(in C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo, development)
** Invoke demo (first_time)
** Execute demo
** Invoke demo 
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Execute build
Building demo
** Invoke demo:build (first_time)
** Invoke C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes (first_time, not_needed)
Compile needed because source file C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/src/main/java/dirwatch/sample/WatchDir.java has no corresponding C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes/dirwatch/sample/WatchDir.class
** Invoke demo:compile (first_time)
** Invoke demo:resources (first_time)
** Execute demo:resources
** Invoke C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/src/main/java (first_time, not_needed)
Compile needed because source file C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/src/main/java/dirwatch/sample/WatchDir.java has no corresponding C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes/dirwatch/sample/WatchDir.class
** Execute demo:compile
mkdir -p C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes
Compiling demo into C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes
javac -classpath C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_27/lib/tools.jar -sourcepath C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/src/main/java -d C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes -nowarn -g C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/src/main/java/dirwatch/sample/WatchDir.java
** Invoke C:/Users/MSI/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.0/ant-1.8.0.jar (first_time)
** Execute C:/Users/MSI/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.0/ant-1.8.0.jar
Downloading org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.0
Downloading org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.0
Requesting http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.0/ant-1.8.0.jar
Exception while invoking prerequisites of task <Rake::FileTask C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes => [demo:compile]>
Exception while invoking prerequisites of task <Rake::Task demo:build => [C:/environment/_work/cikkek/directory_watcher/demo/target/classes, demo:test]>
Exception while invoking prerequisites of task <Rake::Task default => [build]>
Buildr aborted!
RuntimeError : Failed to download org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.0, tried the following repositories:
http://www.ibiblio.org/maven2//
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/packaging/artifact.rb:489:in `fail_download'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/packaging/artifact.rb:449:in `download'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/packaging/artifact.rb:356:in `initialize'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:674:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:660:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:655:in `invoke'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/java/jruby.rb:112:in `load'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/java/jruby.rb:111:in `load'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/java/compiler.rb:68:in `compile'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/compile.rb:262:in `initialize'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:634:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:674:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:660:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:667:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:660:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:667:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:660:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:655:in `invoke'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:326:in `local_task'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:351:in `local_projects'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:351:in `local_projects'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/project.rb:324:in `local_task'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:270:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:220:in `call'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:674:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:660:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:667:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:191:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:660:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:655:in `invoke'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:246:in `top_level'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612:in `each'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:246:in `top_level'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:535:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:237:in `top_level'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:138:in `run'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:535:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/lib/buildr/core/application.rb:135:in `run'
c:/environment/bin/jruby-1.6.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/buildr-1.4.6-java/bin/buildr:19:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063:in `load'
c:\environment\bin\jruby-1.6.5.1\bin\buildr:19:in `(root)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ibibilo mirrors url instead:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/